# ker(π) contains every 2-cycle or it contains no 2-cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

G = $S_{n}$ Suppose H ≤ Sn and [$S_{n}$ : H] = 2

1) Let $\pi: G\rightarrow G/H$ be the quotient map. Show that if ker(π) contains one 2-cycle, then it must contain every 2-cycle.

2) (1) implies either ker(π) contains every 2-cycle or it contains no 2-cycle. Argue that the former is impossible.

This is what I've done so far:

For 1): Since H$\triangleleft$G (by the definition of the map π that sends g to gH and is a surjective homomorphism with kernel H), if it contains one 2-cycle, then it contains all of them:
let $\sigma \in S_{n}$, then  $\exists \alpha \in H$ ( $\sigma$ is a 2-cycle) : $\alpha ' = \sigma\alpha\sigma^{-1}$ Since H is normal, $\alpha'$ is also in H. Therefore, H contains every 2-cycle

I don't really understand how to approach 2). And why does it imply that ker(π) contains every 2-cycle or it contains no 2-cycle. I don't see how it follows from 1).

Answer (score 1):

The $2$-cycles together generate $S_n$, so the only subgroup containing all $2$-cycles is $S_n$ itself. Since the subgroup is of index $2$, it therefore can't contain all $2$-cycles.

As to the rest of your question, the subgroup either contains at least one $2$-cycle or no $2$-cycles, and if it contains at least one then it contains them all.

Comment: Would that mean that in $S_{n}$/H = {e,g} g is also a 2-cycle such that $\pi$(σ) = g, where σ is in $S_{n}$?

Comment: Also, if I am to show that $A_{n}$ = H. I want to just say that since H has index 2, it is therefore equal to $A_{n}$, since $A_{n}$ is the only subgroup of $S_{n}$ with index 2. But then H would contain a 2-cycle, right? Is that not a contradiction?

Comment: @JMK Why would it contain a $2$-cycle?

Comment: Oh, sorry, of course it wouldn't, since $A_{n}$ is even and can't contain a 2-cycle, which is odd. I was thinking about cycle decomposition into 2-cycles and got confused, thanks!

Comment: @JMK No problem.